# How to optimize report queries

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, database-performance

I studied here and there but i couldn't find a way to optimize this query.

```
SELECT  ad_request.user_id,
    ads.req_id,
    ads.id as doneId 
FROM ads
    INNER JOIN ad_request ON ads.req_id = ad_request.req_id 
WHERE 
    (ads.user_id='3612185701') AND ads.date>DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -4 DAY) 
ORDER BY ads.id
```

Query Digest:

```
# Attribute    pct   total     min     max     avg     95%  stddev  median
# ============ === ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= =======
# Count          0     836
# Exec time     17    322s   481us     11s   385ms      2s   956ms    51ms
# Lock time      0   203ms   103us    23ms   242us   332us   787us   185us
# Rows sent     67 209.30k       0   3.56k  256.36   1.46k  478.03    1.96
# Rows examine   1 1021.57k       0  55.08k   1.22k   4.71k   3.05k  202.40
# Rows affecte   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# Query size     0 218.29k     262     268  267.38  258.32       0  258.32
```

the digest is just from a 30-minute frame , sometimes several instances of this query get stuck for +100 sec

Comment: There is a wide variety of "Rows examined" and "Rows sent", so you can expect a wide variety in "Exec time".  Gordon provides the optimal indexes.

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT ar.user_id, a.req_id, a.id AS doneId 
FROM ads a INNER JOIN
     ad_request ar
     ON a.req_id = ar.req_id 
WHERE a.user_id = '3612185701' AND
      a.date > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -4 DAY) 
ORDER BY ads.id;
```

I would start with the following indexes:  `ads(user_id, date, req_id, id)` and `ad_request(req_id, user_id)`.

Also, if `user_id` is not a string, remove the single quotes around `'3612185701'`.  The improper use of types can confuse optimizers as well as people.

Comment: @Desas . . . The way I format queries is explained in Chapter 1 of *Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel*.  Your changes were not an improvement, in my opinion.

Comment: hey man, thanks for response and im really sorry for late respond, i got quite caught up in something and didn't have the time to check
I already had this index "ad_request(req_id, user_id)" but not the other one, is it okay to have such index on a big table? i mean it has 90 million rows and increasing everyday
by the way i already have this indexes on add =>id, add_id, date, req_id,id + req_id, id + add_id,

Comment: and what is the trade off for indexes , time for disk (+ ram?);
and can you tell me where can i learn how to properly query and index? I cant attend to courses right now, but i can read as many as book and articles or see whole youtube channel, if thats what it take for me to really learn and understand this stuff.

Comment: @SeyedMansourMirbehbahani . . . Start with the documentation for the database you are using.